# The server principal owns one or more event notification(s) and cannot be dropped

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to drop a login on SQL server and I get the error.

"The server principal owns one or more event notification(s) and cannot be dropped."

I think it's maybe because the login owns some Server Broker stuff, but I am totally unable to find it. Anyone know how to?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Replace the value `Domain\User` with your login name.

```
SELECT
    s.name AS 'EventNotificationName'
    , p.name AS 'PrincipalName'
    , 'DROP EVENT NOTIFICATION '+s.name+' ON SERVER;' AS 'DropNotificationQuery'
FROM sys.server_event_notifications s
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals p
ON s.principal_id = p.principal_id
WHERE p.name = 'Domain\User';
```